# Code First - ICollection Navigation Property With Foreign Key Throwing “An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.”

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a bit of a gotcha here. I have read through a number of SO threads and not found an answer.

I am using disconnected Repository Pattern for data access, making use of Code First EF.

POCOs:

```
public class LineItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LineItemCategoryMap> LineItemCategoryMaps { get; set; }
}

public class LineItemCategoryMap
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LineItem")]
    public int LineItemId { get; set; }
    public LineItem LineItem { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Data Access Code (update):

```
public void Update(LineItem lineItem)
{
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        db.LineItems.Attach(lineItem);
        db.Entry(lineItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If I have a single LineItemCategoryMap the update works. However if there are two items both with the same LineItemID the exception **"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager."** is thrown.

Creating the LineItem with multiple map objects works 100%

As I see it, LineItem is trying to be attached multiple times. Should it not just reuse the LineItem?

Comment: It seems the exception relates to the Id of your LineItemCategoryMap more than to LineItemId. What are the Ids values ?

Comment: Ah you are right. The Ids are 0. It looks like I should not be using a Key in the intermediate object but rather have a "composite key"

Comment: may be you are not updating, but adding ?

Comment: so attaching works by defining a composite key. Just working on trying  to get changes reflecting on the DB. Will post an answer when it is working :)

Comment: However now changes to the ICollection<LineItemCategoryMap> do not save to the db. No exceptions.

Comment: If you want to update a LineItemCategoryMap (without loading it) you have to attach it to the context.

Comment: marking db.Entry as modified does all properties except http://stackoverflow.com/a/14102487/101662relationships:

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28252/discussion-between-oliver-and-tschmit007)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tschmit007 for spotting that I was trying to readd maps.

I solved this by removing the ID on the LineItemCategoryMap and adding a Composite Key.

```
public class LineItemCategoryMap
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("LineItem")]
    public int LineItemId { get; set; }
    public LineItem LineItem { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately the update code gets a little unsanitary as marking an entity only saves scalar and complex properties not navigational properties (i.e relationships).
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14102487/101662

```
var lineItemToUpdate = (from obj in db.LineItems.Include("LineItemCategoryMaps")
                                             where obj.Id == lineItem.Id
                                             select obj).First();

lineItemToUpdate.LineItemCategoryMaps = lineItem.LineItemCategoryMaps;
lineItemToUpdate.LineItemDepartmentMaps = lineItem.LineItemDepartmentMaps;

db.Entry(lineItemToUpdate).CurrentValues.SetValues(lineItem);

db.SaveChanges();
```

The only way I could get this to work is to fetch the object with the scope of the context and then set the navigational properties.

Does anyone know a cleaner way to do this? Perhaps without the addition database call.

I really wish I could make a Navigation Property as changed.