# Entity Framework many to many relation save issue

Tags: entity-framework

I use entity framework 6.2 code first.
and have some entities. I have two entity with n to n relation.
Book and Genre

```
public class Book
{
   public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

}
```

the problem is, when in new instance of book, I have some genres,
then when I save book the new instance of genres save too.

Edit: as I said before,I can save the book.let explain in this way. I have a record in "Genre" table named "Drama" already, and now I create a new book that the genre "Drama" assigns to it.the "Genres" collection of the "Book" entity now have "Drama" item.But when I save book, I have new record in "Genre" table with "Drama" title. now I have duplicate records in "Genre" table and each time I create a new book, new genres is created too.

Comment: Could you post your code where you instantiate this class and save? Looks like a classic case of EF trying to keep track of changes in your entities.

Comment: Good read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First attach existing Genre to Context, then add Genre to Book.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var genre= new Genre() { Genre= 15 };
    context.Genres.Attach(genre);

    var book= new Book();
    book.Genres.Add(genre);

    context.Books.Add(book);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

[Look at this post **Many to Many Relationships not saving**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098600/many-to-many-relationships-not-saving?newreg=5044cd0470e24fe1ae892ce3e184ebc6)