# How do I insert entities with a 1:n relationship in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I need a 1:n relationship using the Azure App Service. [I followed this tutorial](http://shellmonger.com/2016/05/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-26-relationship-advice/) for the entities.

My client entities (same as tutorial, except I added a constructor):

```
public abstract class Entity {
  // defines id, version, createdAt, updatedAt, deleted
}
public class Animal : Entity {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Zoo : Entity {
  public Zoo() { Animals = new List<Animal>(); }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

My server entities (same as tutorial, except I added a constructor):

```
public class Animal : EntityData {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Zoo : EntityData {
  public Zoo() { Animals = new List<Animal>(); }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

The `ZooController` table controller (stock scaffolded code, except I added attributes):

```
[HttpPatch]
public Task<Zoo> PatchZoo(string id, Delta<Zoo> patch) {
  return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
 }
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostZoo(Zoo item) {
  Zoo current = await InsertAsync(item);
  return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
  }
```

There is a similar table controller for `Animal`.

*Now for the problem.* I perform an insert and an update from the client:

```
// create animal (child)
var animal = new Animal() { Name = "Dumbo" };
await animalTable.InsertAsync(animal);
// create zoo (parent)
var zoo = new Zoo() { Name = "Tokyo National Zoo" };
await zooTable.InsertAsync(zoo);
// add animal to zoo
zoo.Animals.Add(animal);
await zooTable.UpdateAsync(zoo);
// push
await zooTable.MobileServiceClient.SyncContext.PushAsync();
```

This throws exceptions. On the server, it throws with `StatusCode: 409, ReasonPhrase: 'Conflict'`, and on the client it throws with `"The operation failed due to a conflict: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Animals'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Animals'`. Basically, the server is saying that I'm trying to insert the same `Animal` record twice.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did some debugging, and noticed that the `Animal` controller's POST method is called, and after that the `Zoo` controller's POST. So the second POST operation is where the double insert occurs. But how do I stop that?

Comment: Have you tried leaving out animalTable.InsertAsync()? Just a thought I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're running into the Entity Framework "detatched entities" problem. See e.g. [Many to Many Relationships not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098600/many-to-many-relationships-not-saving). The problem is that Entity Framework has not loaded the child item into its context, so it thinks that it needs to insert the child item as well as the parent. (There have been long-standing feature requests in Entity Framework to solve this, but the feature has never been added.)

On the server, you need to check if the referenced child entity already exists in the database, and if it does, just add a reference to the existing item, rather than inserting.

Comment: AHA! Yes you are right. That tutorial made me think there was some magic going on on in the table controller, but actually it's plain old EF. The SDK's magic seems to work best on on the client, not the server! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please try as shown below.

```
// create animal (child)
var animal = new Animal() { Name = "Dumbo" };

// create zoo (parent)
var zoo = new Zoo() { Name = "Tokyo National Zoo" };
zoo.Animals.Add(animal);
await zooTable.InsertAsync(zoo);
```

**Note :** Above code will automatically insert a record to the `animalTable` too due to FK relationship. You don't need to do it manually.

Comment: Yes I would do that if I were using regular EF, but here I believe the entity must be inserted into the client's context. If not, then the `id`, `createdAt`, etc., properties are all null. I could set those on the server in the POST method, but then the client would not know of those values...

Comment: you have to find out workaround for the client scenario. But you cannot do what you have done with the server.That is why it shows the error.If you have a FK relationship then you must do it where I have mentioned it above.No other way.That is the way EF is working.

Comment: Okay, but what if you add the entities at different times? This way they must be done as an atomic operation. If you want to add it later, like in my example, it would fail...

Comment: This is the wrong place.`// add animal to zoo
zoo.Animals.Add(animal);
await zooTable.UpdateAsync(zoo);`

Comment: You're doing same thing twice.

Comment: I think everything you've written is correct on the server side, but it doesn't solve the problem for an Azure App Service. That is what I need to know, because right now it forces me to do it the way I've written above. (I appreciate your help though!)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with this. Here is my solution based on @lindydonna's feedback.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostZoo(Zoo item) {

  // replace child entities with those from the context (so they are tracked)
  if (item.Animals.Any()) {
    // find animals which are already in the db
    var ids = item.Animals.Select(x => x.Id);
    var oldItems = context.Animals.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();    
    var newItems = item.Animals.Where(x => !oldItems.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.Id));

    // add new animals if there are any
    if (newItems.Any()) {
      foreach (var i in newItems) {
        context.Animals.Add(i);
      }
      await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    // replace
    item.Animals.Clear();
    foreach (var i in oldItems) item.Animals.Add(i);
    foreach (var i in newItems) item.Animals.Add(i);
  }

  // now add the Zoo (which contains tracked Animal entities)
  Zoo current = await InsertAsync(item);
  return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
}
```

This works. Though it's probably not performant.

You should probably also add:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Zoo>().HasMany(e => e.Animals);
```

...though for some reason for me it works without as well.

**EDIT**
Better way, which doesn't allow new child entities to be sent together with the parent entity. If that is allowed, then they won't have `id`, `createdAt`, etc. Those child entities should be inserted into the client-side context to populate those properties. Then, when performing a push, the SDK seems to be smart enough to POST them first before POSTing the parent.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostZoo(Zoo item) {

  // replace child entities with those from the context (so they are tracked)
  if ((item.Animals != null) && item.Animals.Any()) {
    // find animals which are already in the db
    var ids = item.Animals.Select(x => x.Id);
    var oldAnimals = _context.Animals.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
    var newAnimals = item.Animals.Where(x => !oldAnimals.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.Id));

    // don't allow new animal entities
    if (tagsNew.Any()) {
      var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      var body = new JObject(new JProperty("error", "New Animals must be added first"));
      response.Content = new StringContent(body.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
      throw new HttpResponseException(response);
      }

    // replace 
    item.Animals.Clear();
    foreach (var i in oldAnimals) item.Animals.Add(i);
    }

  // now add the Zoo (which contains tracked Animal entities)
  Zoo current = await InsertAsync(item);
  return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
  }
```

Comment: This can probably be cleaned up using the context's `Attach()` method.