# Insert record with relationship using OData

Tags: asp.net, azure, odata, azure-mobile-services

This is what my models looks like

```
public User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

public Group
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I using Azure Mobile `TableController` which using OData for CRUD.

Now I trying to insert new user by specifying the id of the group but instead it gives me an error which shows that instead of trying to associate it with my user model it trying to create new one:

```
{
  "message": "The operation failed due to a conflict: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Groups'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Groups'. The duplicate key value is (ad934511a82c4b42ae5427b5228737c6).\r\nThe statement has been terminated.'."
}
```

This is what my post looks like:

```
POST http://localhost/tables/user?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0 HTTP/1.1

{
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '#test',
    group: {
        id: 'ad934511a82c4b42ae5427b5228737c6'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships are not directly supported in Azure Mobile Apps, but you can apply some workarounds to get it to work. Here's a blog post that walks through the scenario: [30 Days of Zumo.v2 (Azure Mobile Apps): Day 26: Relationship Advice](https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-26-relationship-advice/).

The specific problem you're running into is the Entity Framework "detatched entities" problem. See e.g. [Many to Many Relationships not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098600/many-to-many-relationships-not-saving). The problem is that Entity Framework has not loaded the child item into its context, so it thinks that it needs to insert the child item as well as the parent. (There have been long-standing feature requests in Entity Framework to solve this, but the feature has never been added.)

I just posted a similar answer here: [How do I insert entities with a 1:n relationship in Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124741/how-do-i-insert-entities-with-a-1n-relationship-in-azure-app-service)